# Websphere interview questions

Tags: websphere

My boss told me to help in a phone interview with a candidate which is mainly a DB2 admin but claims to have Websphere administration skills. I told my boss I don't know so much about Websphere but he said it doesn't matter, they just wanna be sure the candidate isn't lying in his resume.

What would be a couple of good and basic-intermediate questions for a Websphere administrator and their answers?

(I hope you candidate are not reading this question before your interview, he)

Comment: if they're not, wouldn't that count against them?

Comment: Ask him: "would you recommend websphere?" If he does answer "yes", he's lying :)

Comment: @Pascal haha that's funny! I was thinking on 'Do you like Websphere?'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

perhaps something from http://se9.blogspot.com/2007/05/ibm-websphere-61-administration-test.html they are multiple choice and contain the correct answers so it makes it easier for you to judge if they are correct or not.

I would only use these to judge if they have worked with websphere before and not if they would be a good or bad admin.